# gcloud iam service-accounts list command for SQL instance GCP

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-iam

Is there any **gcloud command** in GCP to list GCP SQL instance **iam service-accounts**. I am able to see in the GCP UI but I need cli command to print it the terminal. Could some one help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such [gcloud command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/sql/instances/describe) to get only the service account of a sql instance, if you want to get the account of an specific instance you can run this in cloud shell or voa Cloud SDK `gcloud sql instances describe instanceName | grep "serviceAccountEmailAddress"` the output will be just then one of the service account.

Answer (score 0):

The `awk` utility can be used to parse the output of the `gcloud sql instances describe` command.

First `gcloud sql instances describe $INSTANCE_NAME` will give you all the information about the instance. Among this is a line line starting with `serviceAccountEmailAddress:`.

To filter to this line we can use the awk `-F` switch, and then output the second section of text from that line:

`gcloud sql instances describe $INSTANCE_NAME | awk -F': '/serviceAccountEmailAddress: /{print $2}'`